# Открытие порта Linux

Tags: linux, сеть, firebird, openvpn, google-cloud

Задача:

1. на gcloud поднять виртуальную машину
2. На ней поднять сервер VPN (OpenVPN)
3. Там же поднять сервер СУБД (Firebird)
4. сделать так, чтобы к СУБД можно было подключаться из VPN тоннеля, но не снаружи

Первые три пункта сделал, с четвертым затык. Удаленного клиента не пускает на порт Firebird.

> Could not open connection to the host, on port 3050: Connect failed

Локальный на localhost:database подключается.

Что нужно еще? Какую диагностику проводить?

Для порта OpenVPN указал разрешение только в консоли gcloud и все заработало. Т.е. никаких манипуляций с ufw не делал. Для Firebird вообще ничего не прописывал ибо, по идее, gcloud о нем ничего знать не должен.

На сервере Ubuntu 21

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. По умолчанию в firebird.conf установлено

```
RemoteBindAdress = localhost
```

заменил на

```
RemoteBindAdress = 10.8.0.1
```

и все заработало